# how to change displaying order of products in wp ecommerce

Tags: e-commerce

I am working on a wp-ecommerce enabled site and am trying to change the display order of the products on the product grid page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the WordPress backend select **Settings** | **Store** .

Select the **Presentation** tab.

Scroll down to the **Product Page Settings** section and change the value of the **Sort Product By** dropdown to: ***Drag & Drop***

Now you are able to click on a product in **Products | Products** , hold it and drag it to the position in which you want it to appear.